# How to use OPENROWSET in SQL Server 2012 to insert data based on the current day in a filename?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have the below script that works, but everyday a new file is saved in the same location with the current day.  Instead of having to change the script daily how can I make the script use the most current filename to insert the data automatically?

Today the filename is 6-day Plan - Daily View August 2.xlsm

tomorrow it will be 6-day Plan - Daily View August 3.xlsm

the day after tomorrow it will be 6-day Plan - Daily View August 4.xlsm and so on.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].['Business SOD$']
SELECT      [LOB]
       ,[Target]
       ,[Forecast]
       ,[Hours Required]
       ,[AHT]
       ,[Abs %]
       ,[OCC %]
       ,[Notes]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                     'Excel 12.0;Database=\\VF_RSOSDCNASUDA\fidopost\National_Command\National Command Centre\ncc\ntsd\syl\6-day Plan - Daily View August 2.xlsm;HDR=YES',
                     'SELECT * FROM [Business SOD$A4:H]')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I dabbled and came up with a solution

```
DECLARE  @SQL varchar(max)='
SELECT      [LOB]
       ,[Target]
       ,[Forecast]
       ,[Hours Required]
       ,[AHT]
       ,[Abs %]
       ,[OCC %]
       ,[Notes]
FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'',
                     ''Excel 12.0;Database=\\VF_RSOSDCNASUDA\fidopost\National_Command\National Command Centre\ncc\ntsd\syl\6-day Plan - Daily View ' + DATENAME(mm,GETDATE()) + ' ' + DATENAME(dd,GETDATE()) + '.xlsm;HDR=YES'',
                     ''SELECT * FROM [Business SOD$A4:H]'')'
                                             INSERT INTO [dbo.].['Business SOD$']
                     EXEC(@SQL)
```